# Exploit of unverified contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan

my question is if it is possible to exploit an unverified contract if you don't have the abi.
Background: Someone deployed an implementation contract without the parent UUPS Proxy contract and used it without initializing the contract. Therefore, the attacker could use this initialize function to claim ownership and withdraw bnb.
Here you can see the transaction history: https://bscscan.com/address/0x27e82185ee7633d5f949eb2c050321d5e0fbfc5f
This leads me to my question how likely is it that someone that is not in possession of the source code or the abi, to just randomly call the initialize function and then a withdraw function inside the contract? Or was it an inside job?
Thanks a lot for the answer in advance!
B.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually might not be the worst "business" idea to monitor all new contract deployments, simulate issuing a `initialize` transaction to them and see if it succeeds. It wouldn't cost anything to simulate it and if it works, it might be profitable in some fashion.

Or, even better - analyze already used contracts to see if some of them can be initialized by you.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the fast response. Yes, definitely, but you also need the "withdraw" function + and, in a lot of cases, the associated parameters (not here). In this example, both functions have been called. So would you say it is conceivable that someone from the outside can obtain that information? Or more like it would be possible, but it is rather unlikely?

Comment: I'd say it's rather unlikely.